# What's the use of .Any() in a C# List<>?

Tags: c#, array, list

I've been discussing this with colleagues, and we couldn't figure out what the use is of [`.Any`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb337697(v=vs.90).aspx) for any given `List<>`, in C#.

You can check the validity of an element in the array like the following statement:

```
if (MyList.Any()){ ...}  //Returns true or false
```

Which is exactly the same as

```
if (MyList.Count() != 0) { ... }
```

and is much more common, readable and clear about the intent of the `if` statement.

In the end, we were stuck with this thought:

> `.Any()` can be used, will work just as well, but is less clear about
>   the intent of the programmer, and it that case it should not be used.

But we feel like this can't be right; we must be missing something.

Are we?

Comment: in what way is any less clear on intent?

Comment: I challenge your claim that `Any()` is less clear:  `Any()` seems more clear to me, especially with a lambda-condition.  Translating code to English in my head, `if(MyList.Count(o => o > 10) > 0)` becomes _"Is the number of items greater than 10 more than 0?"_ whereas `if(MyList.Any(o => o > 10))` becomes _"Are there any items greater than 10?"_

Comment: In some regards, these functions are not well-named. In C++, it would have been `if (!list.empty())`, which seems more related to a list being empty or not. While I am not usually into negating things, `list not empty` is clearer to me than `list any`. Surely, if you insert a `list _has_ any`, it's clearer. But then, Any also has other meanings, e.g. "any true", and you have to put it in mentally, already knowing what "Any" does.

Comment: they are not well-named because they are trying to mimic SQL. (select instead of map, aggregate instead of fold, where instead of filter, etc.); in Haskell this is a lot better.

Comment: @SargeBorsch - only if you prefer Heskel/functional naming, which most people don't.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft i agree.  I think any is more clear since it eliminates a what could be considered a magic number.

Comment: @SargeBorsch any is the same in haskell?

Comment: @SargeBorsch: The SQL parallel to `Any` is `Exists`. The Linq name is probably more inspired by Haskell and Python which also have any/all functions.

Comment: @phresnel: Empty() works when there is no predicate but reads really strange when a predicate is supplied. Any() works in both cases and have a nice symmetry with All(), and the Any()/All() pair have precedence in other languages.

Comment: @JacquesB: Personally, I associate any/none/all with checking for a condition _on_ a list, but not with the meaning of "has any". Probably because there is no symmetry between "list.empty"=="list *is* empty", and "list.any"=="list *has* any". Whereas upon a list, it reads "if any true in list", "if none true in list", "if all true in list". I guess it's that symmetry that makes it less intuitive to me. Personally, while I find it uglier, but I think I would prefer if they'd just stick to "list.hasXXX", "list.isXXX" naming convention, looks less leet, but is less ambiguous.

Comment: With 3 more years of experience behind me (it was my second year of development back in 2015), I do not have the same point of view I had back in the day. After re-reading the question I wrote, I now completely disagree with the intent being unclear.

Comment: Why is this not a question on stackoverflow?

Comment: @KolobCanyon Because on stackoverflow the answer would've been one single line explaining what Any actually does, and not my actual question which is "why would you do it" and not "what does it do ?"

Answer (score 109, accepted):

Keep in mind that `Any` doesn't operate on a `List`; it operates on an `IEnumerable`, which represents a concrete type that may or may not have a `Count` property.  It's true that it's not necessarily the best thing to use on a `List`, but it definitely comes in handy at the end of a LINQ query.  And even more useful than the standalone version is the override that takes a predicate just like `Where`.  There's nothing built in on `List` that's anywhere near as convenient or expressive as the predicate-`Any` extension method.

Also, if you're using `Count()` (the LINQ extension method for IEnumerable), rather than `Count` (the property on `List`), it can have to enumerate the entire sequence [if it can't optimize this away by detecting that your underlying data type has a `Count` Property](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/12/26/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-7-count-and-longcount/).  If you have a long sequence, this can be a noticeable performance hit when you don't really care about what the count is, and just want to know if there are *any* items in the collection.

Comment: This. Performance aside, `Any()` with a predicate is *more* expressive than comparing the override of `Enumerable.Count()` that takes a predicate with 0. :)

Comment: I think this explains the fundamentals so clearly that explains the answer at best.

Comment: IMHO, `Exists` is just as convenient and expressive as `Any`, with a predicate. Using `Count != 0` property on a `List` is more normal than using `Any()`. It's just personal preference.
I've also gone through the effort of changing `_list_.Count()` to `_list_.Count` in my group's code. It made a noticeable difference to me.

Answer (score 61):

There is a run time difference `Count()` can be O(n) where `Any()` is O(1).

Comment: `Count()` also will not halt for infinite iterators, while `Any()` will, since it only needs to call `MoveNext()` once.

Comment: Succinct and accurate, but this reads more as a comment than an answer.  Programmers prefers answers that delve into the _why_  and providing a measure of explanation.  Consider [edit]ing your answer and expanding upon why O(1) might be (is) important.

Comment: very good answer just learned i should use any instead of count==0 :d

Comment: `Any(Func<T>)` is O(n)

Comment: This isn't always true. It depends on the concrete type you call it on, but I can never remember which ones it's not true for. IIRC though, it's never *worse* than `Count`.

Comment: In the specific case of `List`, performance is the same because the extension uses the property. True for all collections implementing the `ICollection` interface.

Comment: @tahatmat i believe linq will use Length for arrays as well.

Answer (score 11):

Actually, keep in mind that there is the [List.Count](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/27b47ht3(v=vs.110).aspx) property, and then there is the [Enumerable.Count](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb338038(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

In your example, you are using the `Enumerable.Count()` method, which has to iterate through every single item of the enumeration to return a result.  That is clearly slower than calling `Any()` which only needs to iterate over the first item, if it exists.

**EDIT:**

In the comments it was pointed out, rightly so, that `Enumerable.Count()` extension method doesn't need to iterate through all the items if it detects that the enumerable also happens to be an `ICollection<T>`.  So in the case of a `List<T>`, using the `Count` property or method doesn't actually make a difference.

[IEnumerable.Count](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,41ef9e39e54d0d0b) source:

```
public static int Count<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source) {
    if (source == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
    ICollection<TSource> collectionoft = source as ICollection<TSource>;
    if (collectionoft != null) return collectionoft.Count;
    ICollection collection = source as ICollection;
    if (collection != null) return collection.Count;
    int count = 0;
    using (IEnumerator<TSource> e = source.GetEnumerator()) {
        checked {
            while (e.MoveNext()) count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: Fair enough. What about the use of the .Count property then? wouldn't that make the read significantly faster, maybe as fast or even faster than calling .Any() ?

Comment: With a `List<T>` the performance difference will be negligible. So just use what you prefer.  But for other types of IEnumerables, you only get to pick between `Count()` (the method), and `Any()`, and in that case, `Any()` will always be the clear winner for your use case and should be preferred.  For what it's worth, I think `Any()` is quite readable and clear.

Comment: @sstan yes unless if the ienumerable can be cast to a collention then it can be optimized and it won't matter.

Comment: `Count()` has the same complexity as `Count` for `ICollection`s, since the extension method then uses the property instead of iterating.

Comment: Linq extensions are optimised for known interfaces - IList , ICollection. Performance discussion here is totally redundant, even if that is an implementation detail

Comment: @tahatmat: Absolutely right. I had not noticed that in the implementation. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 7):

A surprising question - I find the intent of `list.Any()` to be much clearer than the intent of `list.Count()!=0`.

Intent means: If you read someones code (and you didn't write it yourself), is it completely obvious what the programmer wants to achieve and why it written written like it is? If a common problem is solved in a needlessly complex way, you immediately gets suspicious and wonder why the developer didn't use the simple way. You look through the code and try to see if you have missed something. You are afraid to change the code because you worry there is some side effect you are missing and changing it may cause unexpected problems.

The intent of using the `Any()` method is completely clear - you want to know if there are any elements in the list or not.

The intent of the expression `Count()!=0` on the other hand is not obvious for the reader. It is of course not hard to see that the expression tells you if the list is empty or not. The questions arises because you write it this particular way rather than using the standard method. Why do you use `Count()` explicitly? If you really just need to know if there are *any* elements in a list, why do you want to count the whole list first? As soon as you reach 1 you already have have your answer. If the source was an iterator over a large (perhaps infinite) collection or is translated to sql, it could make a big difference performance wise. So maybe the explicit use of Count() is to force a deferred query to execute or to traverse an iterator?

But the source is actually a `List<T>` where `Count()` is O(1) and has no side effects. But if the code relies of this property of `List<T>`, then why not use the `Count`-property which more clearly indicate that you expect an O(1) operation with no side effects?

As it is written, `list.Count()!=0` does exactly the same as `list.Any()` except it is needlessly more complex and the intent is unclear.

Comment: I read both as, "does the list contain any items?" `Count()` has an implied conversion that I would avoid using, but it's not unclear. The compiler may optimize it away, which only makes it careless coding.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe it's just the word? `Any` is an adjective, not really saying anything. Coming from Java, I'd call it `isNonEmpty` which contains a verb. A SQL guy might prefer `EXISTS`. But maybe `Any` fits best in the C# system.

Whatever the word choice, once you get used to it, it *must* be way clearer. Would you ask "Is there `more than zero` beer bottles left". Would you expect `one or more` persons starting to count them before they answer "No, there isn't `any`"?

Comment: The name "any" makes sense when you think of it in terms of LINQ:  `Any()` is really a shortcut for `Any(o => true)`

Comment: I wouldn't normally use empty to describe if an enumerable had anytjing to enumerate over. But "is there **any**thing to enumerate"  seems natural to me, and Any works against any enumeration.